# Reading documentation, specifically bounded traits

Tags: rust

Looking up how to read from stdin in rust-0.13, I got to [this page](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/), which had the following code:

```
for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
    print!("{}", line.unwrap());
}
```

I tried following the docs to figure out what exactly is happening, but got stuck with the lines() function. At the end I went through the code (pretty awesome that they have a link to it in the docs) and found [BufferPrelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#1536) which answered where lines() came from:

```
impl<T: Buffer> BufferPrelude for T {...}
```

My question is - was there an easier to figure what was happening? Does the documentation engine simply not catch this type of logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what's referred to as a *blanket implementation*, i.e. an implementation for all types `T` that already implement `Buffer`, and the documentation system doesn't currently follow transitive implementations like that (i.e. `BufferedReader` impls `Buffer`, and so `BufferPrelude` is "blanket impl'd" for `BufferedReader`).

The quickest way to have found this would've been to look for the method in particular, so `lines`, using the search feature. This would have led you to, indeed, [`BufferPrelude`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufferPrelude.html), where you would notice that it's "only" implemented for types that implement `Buffer`, so you would deduce that `BufferedReader` must implement `Buffer`. To verify this you could click on [`Buffer`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Buffer.html) and look at the "implementors" at the bottom.